# How to hide the footer on mobile

Tags: html, css, textbox, hide, footer

The page footer should hide when a user tries to input something in the fields **on mobile devices**!

[Live link to the site](http://www.talmax.co.il/test)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Your help please :)

Comment: Please add some code. And a screenshot would be better than a link to your site.

Comment: Just to clarify @TotZam's comment, add a screenshot of how your site looks and paste your code in the question and format it by clicking CTRL+K or the `{}` button. _Don't_ post a screenshot of your code.

Comment: Improved the question and added a mobile snapshot of the provided URL.

Comment: screenshot was added... your help please

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you want the footer to disappear when you click on the input box? If so, you could try something like this:

CSS

```
@media (max-width: /* Whatever size you want */) {
    .hidden {
         display: none;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
/* Hide footer when input is focused */
$('input').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
});

/* Reveal footer when input is blurred */
$('input').on('blur', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Also, you will need this CDN for jQuery: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` Good luck!

Comment: OP will have to load jQuery too (It's not the case actually). You should suggest a CND to him... And where and how to add it. ;)

Comment: i didnt want the footer to disappear when click on the input box, i want that keyboard will hide the footer

Comment: @MaximBaranFurman In this case, they're practically the same thing. I would try the above code and see what happens.